# Django & CouchDB - Common authentication backend

Tags: django, authentication, ldap, couchdb

Here's the setup:
I'm using Django with MySQL for a web app. I want to add CouchDB for storing user data. I want to have CouchDB's API's exposed so that clients can connect directly to CouchDB (for using the awesome replication API with mobile clients, among other things) and I want users to be able to log into the Django web app via browser.

What is the best way to enforce a common authentication between CouchDB and Django? If a mobile client accesses CouchDB directly, I want the login credentials to be consistent with what Django uses. Is LDAP the best way to implement this? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is currently no ready-made solution for you.

You possible routes are:

- Make Django use CouchDB's authentication system.
- Make CouchDB use Django's authentication system.
- Make a third party back end that is the auth system and hook it into both Django and CouchDB.

They all require work. #3 could be LDAP, but currently there is no LDAP adapter for CouchDB, although it wouldn't be very hard to write. #1 would be useful to others as well I'd think.

Comment: +1 I agree, having consistent credentials across a webapp like Django and an awesome http API from CouchDB would be great. Do you know of any good documentation on writing a CouchDB authentication module?

Comment: Here's an example of case #1: https://github.com/theju/django-couchdb-utils/tree/master/django_couchdb_utils/auth, but I'd like to find out how to do case #2...

Comment: @jan-lehnardt What about using CouchDB and Django auth in parallel, I mean create two users and when you login or signup hit both backends?